# Use two data connections from the same database

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel document, I have two data connections, both pointing to different views in the same database on the same SQL Server.

I have them both set to refresh on restart (I think I actually put it into a VBA macro, as opposed to checking the box).

It asks me to put in the password twice--one for each data connection, even though it's the same username and password each time.

Is there any way to either "Remember" the password, or at least let me log in only once?